# Symfony: Choicetype Field not returning in Request when no option is selected

Tags: php, forms, request, symfony5, multiple-choice

I want to get in the Request the field with an empty value, null or [ ] or whatever.

The form field looks like this

```php
->add('preferencia', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'  => [
        'Catamaranes de vela' => 'Vela',
        'Catamaranes de motor' => 'Motor',
        'Trimaranes' => 'Trimaranes',
    ], 
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'mapped' => false,
    'required' => false,
])
```

And I think that is all the necessary code. Just in case, in the controller I get the submitted result with

```php
$result = $request->request->all("curriculo_nautico_form");
```

When the form is submitted without any choice selected,  `$result` is missing that field, I want to still return the field but with an empty array or whatever. Like

```php
$result['preferencia'] = []||null||something
```

I know I can just check manually if the field was retrieved, but I'm using this type of field several times so I want to automate it.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: When you use a form type, you must let the form component [handle the request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#handling-form-submissions). Directly accessing the request data bypasses everything you set up with the form.

Comment: I do use the handleRequest(). Should I use getData() instead of my method? Will that solve my problem or is it just good practice?

Comment: You absolutely must use `getData` or use the object you passed as data when you created the form. As I said, using the request directly bypasses all form-handling.

Comment: Thank you, I used the getData() and ended up using non data_class for the form instead of the object, so the  data array always returns every field even if it is empty. :)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing this problem, I ended up using getData() and using non data_class for the form instead of the object, so the data array always returns every field even if it is empty.